# Flash.ocx dependencies cannot be added

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, setup-project

Unable to create setup file in visual studio as this error is being thrown. What are the dependencies that should be added and how. Can anyone help

Thanks
Deera

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but you do realize that "*[starting January 2021](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/update-adobe-flash-support) ... Microsoft will also take steps to remove Flash from the Windows operating system*".

Comment: In this case, what would be the solution. I think this is because of crystal reports. Please help if you know a way

Comment: Don't know about that, I'll leave it to others more familiar with crystal reports.